# Get match start position. in text

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

When I do check for matches using Postgres' Full Text Search (FTS) I wonder if there is a way to figure out where in the text the match occurs? Is it possible to get the starting and end position?

For example, here is a simple match:

```sql
select to_tsvector('simple', 'Free text seaRCh is a wONderful Thing') @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'wonderful thing');
```

Using the `ts_headline` I can highlight where the match happens:

```sql
select ts_headline('Free text seaRCh is a wonderful Thing',
        phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'wonderful thing'));
```

Which produces:

```
                     ts_headline
═════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 Free text seaRCh is a <b>wonderful</b> <b>Thing</b>
(1 row)
```

So, this function knows the start and end position of the match. Is there a way to extract both positions?

Answer (score -1):

Using the tsvector, tsquery, and ts_stat functions in FTS , you can extract the positions of the matched terms in a document . Try this code;

```
-- Create a tsvector from the document
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'Free text seaRCh is a wonderful Thing') AS doc_vector;

-- Create a tsquery from the query
SELECT phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'wonderful thing') AS query_tsquery;

-- Use the @@ operator to check if the query matches the document
SELECT to_tsvector('simple', 'Free text seaRCh is a wonderful Thing')
    @@ phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'wonderful thing') AS is_match;

-- Use ts_stat to get the positions of the matched terms
SELECT ts_stat('simple',
               to_tsvector('simple', 'Free text seaRCh is a wonderful Thing'),
               phraseto_tsquery('simple', 'wonderful thing')
              ) AS term_positions;
```

One row is returned by the ts_stat function for each term in the query. Information about the term, including where it appears in the document, is provided in each row.

Hope it works to solve your problem :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct since ts_stat takes a select statement as input. It appears this function is used for term frequency.